# Automatic conversion between tuples and Record

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

Record or simple ADT in haskell are pretty much equivalent to *boxed* tuples.
Is there a way (ideally some fancy extensions or a lib from the haksell platform) which allow conversion between such type and tuples ?

I'm (fairly ) new to haskell and I'm trying to build some reporting tool in Haskell. This involves reading/writing csv files and database tables. Things are pretty much straight forward using tuples, but involve a bit of boiler plate when using plain class. 
The boilerplate seams nearly identical in both way, but I didn't find a nice way to do it only once, except maybe from doing a conversion (data <-> tuple) and use the native conversion from tuple to CSV/table.

### Update

All the answer I got back so far, assumes that I need something totally generic and I want tuple.
I don't want tuple, I **have** tuple and I don't want them, therefore the need to convert them.
In fact I just want to reduce the boiler plate (to 0 :-)) but I don't need necessarily the function(s) to have the same name for every types.

For example I can easily convert a tuple to anything by uncurrying one of its constructors.
The problem is I need uncurryN which I can't find anywhere (except in a template haskell tutorial).
The reverse is harder to do.

I'm not asking for a solution (althout all the answers I got are greats because I'm not familiar whith the different way of meta-programming in Haskell) but more, as I don't like to reinvent the wheel, if the wheel existed already (for example this uncurryN, could have been written by hand till 20 and packed in nice package)

## Updated2

Apparently a uncurry package exists, but it stills solves half the problem.

Comment: You might want to try [SYB](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/hmap/).

Comment: I would like to avoid using template haskell. Is not SYB using it ?

Comment: No, SYB doesn't use TH, all you need is `deriving (Data)`

Answer (score 8):

You might want to look at [GHC.Generics](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC.Generics). It basically encodes each ADT as products (`(,)`) and sums (`Either`). As an example, here is how you could show this representation using generics:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import GHC.Generics

class Tuple p where
  showRepresentation :: p -> String

  default showRepresentation :: (Generic p, GTuple (Rep p)) => p -> String
  showRepresentation = gshowRepresentation . from

class GTuple p where
  gshowRepresentation :: p x -> String

instance Tuple k => GTuple (K1 i k) where
  gshowRepresentation (K1 t) = showRepresentation t

instance GTuple f => GTuple (M1 i c f) where
  gshowRepresentation (M1 f) = gshowRepresentation f

instance (GTuple f, GTuple g) => GTuple (f :*: g) where
  gshowRepresentation (f :*: g) = gshowRepresentation f ++ " * " ++ gshowRepresentation g

-- Some instances for the "primitive" types
instance Tuple Int where showRepresentation = show
instance Tuple Bool where showRepresentation = show
instance Tuple () where showRepresentation = show

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
data Example = Example Int () Bool deriving Generic
instance Tuple Example

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ showRepresentation $ Example 3 () False
-- prints: 3 * () * False
```

You can find more documentation in the [GHC.Generics](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/GHC-Generics.html) module. I also found the paper about it, [A Generic Deriving Mechanism for Haskell](http://dreixel.net/research/pdf/gdmh.pdf) to be quite readable (it was one of the few papers I read).

Answer (score 4):

The [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) library,  in modules [Control.Lens.Iso](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.1.2/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html) and [Control.Lens.Wrapped](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.1.2/docs/Control-Lens-Wrapped.html), has a few utilities that make working with such conversions easier. Unfortunately, at the moment the Template Haskell [machinery](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.1.2/docs/Control-Lens-TH.html#v%3amakeWrapped) for such cases does not handle records, only newtypes, so you'll have to define the instances yourself. For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Control.Lens

data Foo = Foo { baz :: Int, bar :: Int } deriving Show

instance Wrapped Foo where
  type Unwrapped Foo = (Int,Int)
  _Wrapped' = iso (\(Foo baz' bar') -> (baz',bar')) (\(baz',bar') -> Foo baz' bar')
```

Now we can wrap and unwrap easily:

```
*Main> (2,3) ^. _Unwrapped' :: Foo
Foo {baz = 2, bar = 3}

*Main> Foo 2 3 ^. _Wrapped'
(2,3)
```

We can also modify a `Foo` using a function that works on the tuple:

```
*Main> over _Wrapped' (\(x,y)->(succ x,succ y))  $ Foo 2 5
Foo {baz = 3, bar = 6}
```

And the reverse:

```
*Main> under _Wrapped' (\(Foo x y)->(Foo (succ x) (succ y)))  $ (2,5)
(3,6)
```

Comment: I like that lots. However, are you suggesting that Haskell template support it for newtype ? What would that be ?

Comment: If you just have a `newtype` instead of a record, you can use `$(makeWrapped ''NameOfTheNewtype)` to automatically generate the `Wrapped` instance using TH. It could work for records as well, but it doesn't seem to be implemented at the moment.

Comment: `makePrisms` for a single-constructor type actually generates the `Iso` we're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want real n-tuples (and not just some other data that is semantically equivalent) it's going to be cumbersome without Template Haskell.

For example, if you want to convert

```
data Foo = Foo Int String Int
data Bar = Bar String String Int Int
```

into

```
type FooTuple = (Int, String, Int)
type BarTuple = (String, String, Int, Int)
```

both `GHC.Generics` and `SYB` will be problematic because the result type needs to be different depending on the fields of the datatype. Even though both are calle "tuples", `(Int, String, Int)` and `(String, String, Int, Int)` are completely separate types and there are no convenient ways to work with n-arity tuples in a generic fashion. Here's one way to achieve the above using `GHC.Generics`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

-- Generic instance to turn generic g x into some n-tuple whose exact
-- type depends on g.
class GTuple g where
    type NTuple g

    gtoTuple :: g x -> NTuple g

-- Unwarp generic metadata
instance GTuple f => GTuple (M1 i c f) where
    type NTuple (M1 i c f) = NTuple f

    gtoTuple = gtoTuple . unM1

-- Turn individual fields into a Single type which we need to build up
-- the final tuples.
newtype Single x = Single x

instance GTuple (K1 i k) where
    type NTuple (K1 i k) = Single k

    gtoTuple (K1 x) = Single x

-- To combine multiple fields, we need a new Combine type-class.
-- It can take singular elements or tuples and combine them into
-- a larger tuple.
--
class Combine a b where
    type Combination a b
    combine :: a -> b -> Combination a b

-- It's not very convenient because it needs a lot of instances for different
-- combinations of things we can combine.

instance Combine (Single a) (Single b) where
    type Combination (Single a) (Single b) = (a, b)
    combine (Single a) (Single b) = (a, b)

instance Combine (Single a) (b, c) where
    type Combination (Single a) (b, c) = (a, b, c)
    combine (Single a) (b, c) = (a, b, c)

instance Combine (a,b) (c,d) where
    type Combination (a,b) (c,d) = (a,b,c,d)
    combine (a,b) (c,d) = (a,b,c,d)

-- Now we can write the generic instance for constructors with multiple
-- fields.

instance (Combine (NTuple a) (NTuple b), GTuple a, GTuple b) => GTuple (a :*: b) where
    type NTuple (a :*: b) = Combination (NTuple a) (NTuple b)

    gtoTuple (a :*: b) = combine (gtoTuple a) (gtoTuple b)


-- And finally the main function that triggers the tuple conversion.
toTuple :: (Generic a, GTuple (Rep a)) => a -> NTuple (Rep a)
toTuple = gtoTuple . from

-- Now we can test that our instances work like they should:
data Foo = Foo Int String Int deriving (Generic)
data Bar = Bar String String Int Int deriving (Generic)

fooTuple = toTuple $ Foo 1 "foo" 2
barTuple = toTuple $ Bar "bar" "asdf" 3 4
```

The above works but it requires a lot of work (and I couldn't quickly figure out
if it could be done without using `UndecidableInstances`).

Now what you *really* want to do is probably just skip the tuples and use generics
to convert directly to CSV. I'm assuming you are using [`csv-conduit`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/csv-conduit) and want to generate instances of the `ToRecord` type-class.

Here's an example of that

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import Data.CSV.Conduit.Conversion

class GRecord g where
    gToRecord :: g x -> [ByteString]

instance GRecord f => GRecord (M1 i c f) where
    gToRecord = gToRecord . unM1

instance ToField k => GRecord (K1 i k) where
    gToRecord (K1 x) = [toField x]

instance (GRecord a, GRecord b) => GRecord (a :*: b) where
    gToRecord (a :*: b) = gToRecord a ++ gToRecord b

genericToRecord :: (Generic a, GRecord (Rep a)) => a -> Record
genericToRecord = record . gToRecord . from
```

And now you can easily make instances for your custom types.

```
data Foo = Foo Int String Int deriving (Generic)
data Bar = Bar String String Int Int deriving (Generic)

instance ToRecord Foo where
    toRecord = genericToRecord

instance ToRecord Bar where
    toRecord = genericToRecord
```

In response to your updated question: you might be interested in the [`tuple`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple) package (and especially [`Curry`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple-0.2.0.1/docs/Data-Tuple-Curry.html)) which contains implementations for `uncurryN` and `curryN` for tuples up to 15 elements.

Comment: I can't skip the tuple if I'm using `simple-mysql-quasi` for example. Althouth as specified in my update, I don't need necessarily one class, I probably could get away with a GTuple2, GTuple3 ... etc

Comment: Added a link to the `tuple` package which you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you can use [unsafeCoerce](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Unsafe-Coerce.html). The name of the function should be quite a clear warning to be very careful. Particularly, the behavior is dependent on the compiler and even compiler version.

```
data Bar = Bar Text Text

tupleToBar :: (Text, Text) -> Bar
tupleToBar = unsafeCoerce
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `_Ctor` in `generic-lens` converts any record value to a tuple and vice versa with no template haskell.